# Why is ionisation energy defined for gaseous species?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Most high school and college textbooks usually define the first ionisation energy as such:

> The first ionisation energy is the energy required to remove 1 mole of electrons from one mole of **gaseous atoms** in the ground state to form 1 mole of gaseous singly-charged cations.

I've not been able to receive a satisfactory answer from my teachers, as they either admit they do not know, or treat it as a convention.

Is there a rationale for this definition? Thank you :)

Comment: Have a look at: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/why-is-ionization-energy-definition-restricted-to-gaseous-atoms